# Ligações dentro da aplicação

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Estou tentando fazer a minha aplicação fazer uma chamada de emergência e ligar para um numero de emergência pré definido, mas quando abro a `Activity` ela simplesmente para já olhei e refiz o código 3 vezes, mas o erro persiste,  ela apresenta o seguinte erro:

### Stack trace:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                     Process: com.example.matheus.privatewalletm, PID: 3321
>                                                                                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method ligacao(View)
>   in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined
>   on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id
>   'buttonligar'
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

```
    public class Ligar extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private Button buttonligar;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ligacao);

        buttonligar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonligar);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {


        String telefone = "190";
        try {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:" + telefone);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, uri);

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dlg.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string._menssagem));
        dlg.show();

        }


    }
}
```

**XML**

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonligar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ligar Emergencia"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="OnClick"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: você escreveu "OnClick" em vez de "onClick" no XML. Pode ser isso.

Comment: obrigado por notar esse detalhe... mas ainda não resolveu o problema

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente você precisa tratar as questões do seu botão, inserindo o `setOnClickListener()` desta forma:

```
buttonligar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonligar);
buttonligar.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Aí depois você pode criar uma função para o tratamento relacionado as permissões

```
public boolean getPermissionCall(Context context) {
        int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CALL = 221;
        boolean res = true;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                res = false;
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{
                                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                        REQUEST_PERMISSION_CALL);

            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Assim, toda vez que for fazer a ligação, você primeiro verifica se sua permissão ao `CALL_PHONE`. Seu `onClick` ficará desta forma:

```
public void onClick(View view) {

        if(getPermissionCall(this)){
            String telefone = "190";
            try {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:" + telefone);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, uri);

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    return;
                }
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                dlg.setMessage("teste");
                dlg.show();

            }
        }
    }
```

Boa sorte!